# PHP, Add gmdate to gmdate

Tags: php

I have a code that looks like this:

```
        $dagtidhelg = gmdate('H:i', $diffMorning) . "\n";
        $kvallstidhelg = gmdate('H:i', $diffNight);
```

This code runs several times per page since its runt every time a row is loaded from mysql.
It can return a time value ie 08:15 and 09:30. This is the lenght of two work sessions.

That works great but now Im stuck, I want to display the total of every work session at the bottom. I have tried this:

```
        $dagtidhelgtotal = $dagtidhelgtotal + $dagtidhelg;
        $kvalltidhelgtotal = $kvalltidhelgtotal + $kvallstidhelg;
```

But that only adds the hours togheter, it wont even display the :
So Im guessing that Im doing this totaly wrong.

How can I add these times togheter? Maybe convert them to minutes, then add them all togheter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add duration together is simple .But you must keep in mind that duration and date are two things completely different. You can write 100:08 for duration but not for date. If your purpose is to keep a duration counter on(one or) every page(s) you need to build a system based on  `$_SESSION` variable.
To add two duree you can proceed like this:

```
function addDuration($duration1,$duration2){

        $result=array_map(function($x,$y){return sprintf("%'.02d", $x+$y);},explode(':',$duration1),explode(':',$duration2));
        if($result[1]>60){
            $result[0]=sprintf("%'.02d",$result[0]+(int)$result[1]/60);
            $result[1]=sprintf("%'.02d",$result[1]%60);
        }elseif($result[1]==60){
            $result[1]="00";
            $result[0]=sprintf("%'.02d",$result[0]+1);
        }
        return  join(':',$result);
}
```

and the usage in your case could be:

```
 $dagtidhelgtotal = addDuration($dagtidhelgtotal,$dagtidhelg);
```

if we suppose that

```
$dagtidhelgtotal ==='100:09' && $dagtidhelg === '08:08'
```

then after the addition 
  `$dagtidhelgtotal` will be equal to `'108:17'`;

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, but I have to ask, is the addDuration part PHP? seems more like javascript. That wont be a problem anyhow :)

Comment: No you can try it on your code.It is purely PHP. Don't forget to mark your question solved if this answer really helps you.

Comment: Do I only have to paste in the function once? Even if I have many if statements? Then just use ie $dagtidhelgtotal = addDuration($dagtidhelgtotal,$dagtidhelg); in every statement?

Comment: addDuration is just a function you can use it exactly like any PHP function .It takes two arguments which must be duration in the format you specified above hour:min eg: `addDuration('08:08','09:09')` will return `'17:17'`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the lession. Will be back att leta you know when I have tried it :)

Comment: This code worked perfectly! Now I just need to figure out how to convert the total time to minutes, I need to see the total salary for dagtime/nighttime/daytimeweekend/nighttimeweekend